# app.UseCors is useful for which security context

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

In web API, enabled Cors in Owin `Startup` file as below:

```
  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

I understood, its use for below two securities, is it correct understanding ?

1) Allow other domain web api request from WEB API ?  (request out going from web api)

2) Accept javascript request from other domain for this web API ? (request incoming to web api)

I want to ensure the security context for API.

Comment: It's to define the level of security for incoming API calls.  Allow other origins or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**CORS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) means Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. This is when another [**origin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) request to the current origin and this origin can accept that request and give a response. You can allow some origins to work with your origin and other don't let to do it for security reasons.

Second case which you mentioned is not related to `CORS` meaning.

From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

> CORS defines a way in which a browser and server can interact to
>   determine whether or not it is safe to allow the cross-origin request

First case is true, what about the second case - it can be not only Javascript request, but also a request from another server or web api, which has another origin

Comment: Ok, So, for second point, WEB API to accept the request from any client (which has different origin/domain), it needs to have cors enabled in main WEB API (where client is requesting)? is it correct ?  As my API will be consumed by different origin API and it should accept request.

Comment: @user3711357 Yes, the CORS is enabled from server side. It is for the server secure.

Comment: Ok. Make sense. Thanks. Needs to cors enable in web api as it will be requesting from corss origin scenarios.